# Do researchers at schools that publish good journals get priority in publishing in those journals?

Tags: research-process, journals, journal-workflow, politics

Take mathematics, for an example.

Do Princeton math professors get any sort of priority / preferential treatment in publishing in the Annals?

Do Duke math professors get any priority in publishing in the Duke Mathematics Journal?

What about more applied places - do NYU Courant professors get any priority in publishing in Communications in Pure and Applied Mathematics?

My question is generally about priority / preferential treatment, not about specific schools or journals.

Comment: Good journals: no.  Iffy journals, yes.  In fact, some journals publish only the papers of the editor and his friends.

Comment: The current chief editor of the Duke Mathematics Journal is a professor at [UNC](http://www.unc.edu), of all places, so if anything you might expect Duke faculty to have [a harder time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carolina%E2%80%93Duke_rivalry) publishing there.

Comment: CPAM is a special case -- from what I recall, any paper has to be communicated by a NYU Courant faculty.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, that's interesting :)

Comment: @DanRomik, would you like to convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it?  Thanks,

Comment: It might seem that these journals publish more papers from 'top' people/schools.  This simply reflects the quality of their work/environment; Indeed, their personal brand name says 'quality'.  Otherwise, they would never be in places like Princeton in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is certainly not - not officially anyhow - except insofar as being a well known mathematician (which someone who is at a place like Princeton typically is) makes it easier to get one's paper accepted to a fancy journal. That effect is likely real (though of a magnitude that would be difficult or impossible to measure, and hopefully not too large), but it typically applies on a more global level rather than a journal-locale-based level.